# Having multiple htaccess in a root directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

I have directory in my website where user can upload projects or create sub directories, in the root dir i have a default `.htaccess` file and `default.php` which i don't want the user to get access to because i rewrite the dir to load default.php as default index page and also this to file will be copied to any sub dir that the user create.
Now my problem is when user try to save .htaccess for the project he want to save it will show that is already exist. is there anything i can do to have multiple htaccess or write my own as default htaccess.

Second. is it possible to use one htaccess in all the sub dir so user can freely add their own?
Example: bellow is how my directory look

> WWW.example.com/ **project** /userprojectname/sub1/sub2/sub3/etc...

In *project* it has htaccess and users are not allow to do anything but their projectname will save there.
In `userprojectname` it has an `htaccess` and `default.php`, they can also add more file or create directories and any sub dir will also have it own htaccess and default.php.

Now can i make htaccess in **project** work in all page? and as for default, i used jquery to disallow users creating file name `default.php` also is there a better way i can fix all this?

Bellow is my dirs and htacess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

#This will block from accessing root folder
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

DirectoryIndex default.php
```

Comment: @Alex Do you have access to Apache .conf files?

Comment: @anubhava the htaccess they save will not take any effect in my server it only csn work when day download it for use

Comment: @DusanBajic where can i see it from my cpanel?

Comment: I am not familiar with cpanel, but the files are usually in /etc/httpd/conf.d

Comment: @DusanBajic i can't find it in my cp